# c# updater help ( restart once update is complete )

Tags: c#

Hello all i have managed to make a basic program that will do a update for me but one thing i want to try and do when the update form is open to close the main form then restart program when the update is finished but have no idea how to do this

this is the code i have currently

```
namespace update_test
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // folder calls needed 
        string updatepath = Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "updatetest");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    // copying files 
    private static void DirectoryCopy(
    string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        // If the destination directory does not exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }


        // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

            // Copy the file.
            file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
        }

        // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {

            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                // Create the subdirectory.
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

                // Copy the subdirectories.
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }

    public void downloadfile()
    {
        //client.DownloadFile("http://elfenliedtopfan5.co.uk/update/elfenlied_weapons.zip", updatepath);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string file = Path.Combine(updatepath, "elfenlied_weapons.zip");
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://elfenliedtopfan5.co.uk/update/elfenlied_weapons.zip"), file);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
        MessageBox.Show(file);

    }

    void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int bytesin = int.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        int totalbytes = int.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        int kb1 = bytesin / 1024;
        int kb2 = totalbytes / 1024;

        label1.Text = kb1.ToString() + "KB out of " + kb2.ToString() + "KB (" +e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%)";
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

       if (e.ProgressPercentage == 100)
       {
           exactzip();
       }
    }


    public void update()
{
    string downloadurl = "";
    Version newversion = null;
    string xmlurl = "http://elfenliedtopfan5.co.uk/xml/update.xml";
    XmlTextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlurl);
        reader.MoveToContent();
        string elementname = "";
        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)&& (reader.Name == "update_test"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
              {
                  elementname = reader.Name;
              }
                else
              {
                  if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)&& (reader.HasValue))
                  {
                      switch (elementname)
                      {
                          case "version":
                          newversion = new Version(reader.Value);
                          break;

                          case "url":
                          downloadurl = reader.Value;
                          break;

                      }
                  }
              }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
        finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
    Version applicationvershion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    if (applicationvershion.CompareTo(newversion) < 0)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Version " + newversion.Major + "." + newversion.Minor + "." + newversion.Build + " of elfenliedprograms do you want to update now ?", "Update Avalible!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            var myForm = new Form1();
            myForm.Show();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            //do something else
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("program currently upto date :) ");
        }
    }
}


    public void seeiffile()
    {
        // Set to folder path we must ensure exists.
        string updatepathex = updatepath;
        try
        {
            // If the directory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(updatepathex))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(updatepathex);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }


    // if all above works then follow this 

    public void exactzip()
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read (Path.Combine(updatepath, "elfenlied_weapons.zip")))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
            {
                e.ExtractExistingFile = ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently;
                e.Extract(updatepath);
               // e.Extract(updatepath);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seeiffile();
        downloadfile();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowHideForm1(true);
    }
    private void ShowHideForm1(bool show)
    {
        Form1 f1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (f1 != null)
        {
            if (show)
            { f1.Show(); }
            else
            { f1.Hide(); }
        }
    }

    private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowHideForm1(false);
    }
}
```

}

then i have another form attached to this application called 
elfenliedprograms.cs

witch contains this code

```
namespace update_test
```

{
    public partial class elfenliedprograms : Form
    {
        public elfenliedprograms()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void elfenliedprograms_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        update();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        string downloadurl = "";
        Version newversion = null;
        string xmlurl = "http://elfenliedtopfan5.co.uk/xml/update.xml";
        XmlTextReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlurl);
            reader.MoveToContent();
            string elementname = "";
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "update_test"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        elementname = reader.Name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
                        {
                            switch (elementname)
                            {
                                case "version":
                                    newversion = new Version(reader.Value);
                                    break;

                                case "url":
                                    downloadurl = reader.Value;
                                    break;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
        }
        Version applicationvershion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
        if (applicationvershion.CompareTo(newversion) < 0)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Version "+ newversion.Major + "." + newversion.Minor + "." + newversion.Build + " of elfenliedprograms do you want to update now ?", "Update Avalible!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                var myForm = new Form1();
                myForm.Show();




            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //do something else
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("program currently upto date :) ");
            }
        }
    }
```

so basically once the update triggers there is a update it will call elfenliedprograms.cs but it will not shut down the main form if i do that it will shut the whole process down and im not sure how to go about making it download then restart app so all new stuff is updated it has taken me a good 4 months just to get this working the way i want not very good when it comes to updating a aplication so i would need help on this part sorry to be a pain and ask

thank you for

Comment: Usually updaters are separate processes so it can update the program, otherwise it can't copy over the files while the program is running.

Comment: ok this may be a very noob question and im really sorry for that if it is but i can make it a separate program but how can i add it into another application and get it to work ? or more to the point integrate it into a seprate application